# Alias a function in Python

Tags: python

I would like a copy of the `print` function that is called `debug`. How can I alias a function in Python?

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file will make Python 2 use the Python 3 version of `print`, so that you can do `debug = print`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can simply assign `debug = print` in Python 3.

In Python 2 `print` isn't a function. There no way to give yourself a `debug` statement that works exactly like `print` (`print 1,`, `print 1 >> sys.stderr` etc.). Best you can do is write a wrapper around the `print` statement:

```
def debug(s):
    print s
```

You can also disable the `print` statement and use the Python 3 version:

```
from __future__ import print_function
debug = print
```

If you do this, you cannot use the statement version (`print x`) anymore. It's probably the way to go if you're not breaking any old code.

Comment: You can simply do this `debug=print` After you're done that you can now on use `debug()` to print e.g. `debug("Hi")` will print "Hi"
For python 2, I'm not as sure but I think It should be the same `debug=print` and to print `debug "Hi"`

Answer (score 16):

In Python 2.x you can do:

```
def debug(s):
    print(s)
```

In 3.x you can just use assignment:

```
debug = print
```

Comment: You don't need the parens after `print` in Python 2.

Comment: This is true, but why not keep it 2/3 compatible where you can?

Comment: But you *must* look into the `__future__`! `__pun__` intended.

Answer (score 3):

You can just define a new function `debug` like:

```
def debug(text):
    print text
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your version of Python. Python 3 simply allows you to do this:

```
debug = print
```

However, older versions consider `print` to be a built-in keyword, so you have to wrap it in your own function:

```
def debug(msg):
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `def` method has the advantage that tracebacks more clearly identify the alias. This could help a user who says, "What's '`print`'?" if they only use `debug` (the alias):

```
>>> def f():
...  print x
>>> g = f
>>> g()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
>>> 
>>> def h():
...  return f()
... 
>>> h()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in h
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```